# How handle Node.js when performing ajax calls when running Mongoose finds

Tags: jquery, ajax, node.js, express, mongoose

I was building a simple test app with node, express and mongoose. My problem is understanding what I should do with node?
The function below is called via a standard $.ajax call from clientside, the bit I don't understand is at line 111, I need to perform a find operation but that is async so the result is not available and we will get a call back at line 112 when the find results are ready from Mongo, but what do I do at the bottom of this function should I use the next tick function while I am waiting for the search results?

I have looked around and I am sure the answer is already there but I just can't find it plus I think my explaining around node.js is poor so please take pity I'm sure you know what I'm asking.

```
exports.loginAuthenticate = function(mongoose){
  96     return function(req, res){
  97         var error = { errorCode: 0, errorMessage:"No error" };
  98 
  99         if(req.body.Username==null || typeof req.body.Username=="undefined" || req.body.Username.length==0){
 100             error.errorCode=1;error.errorMessage="You MUST specify a username before attempting to login.";
 101         }
 102         if(req.body.Password==null || typeof req.body.Password=="undefined" || req.body.Password.length==0){
 103             error.errorCode=1;error.errorMessage="You MUST specify a password before attempting to login.";
 104         }
 105 
 106         if(error.errorCode!=0){ res.send(error); return; }
 107 
 108         mongoose.connect("mongodb://localhost/nm", function(err){
 109 
 110             var client = mongoose.model("Client");
 111             client.findOne({ Username: req.body.Username }, "Password", function(err, found){
 112                 if(err){
 113                     console.log("findOne -> Error!");
 114                     return;
 115                 }
 116 
 117                 if(found!=null){
 118                     if(req.body.Password!=found._doc.Password){
 119                         error.errorCode=1;
 120                         error.errorMessage="Sorry your username or password is invalid.";
 121                     }
 122                 }
 123                 else{
 124                     error.errorCode=1; // Did not find the user within the system
 125                 }
 126                 res.send(error);
 127                 return;
 128             });
 129 
 130         });
 131 
 132     return;
 133     };
 134 };
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code should work as you expect - you use `res.send()` to send back the results - either an error, success or whatever you want.  It can also be asynchronous so having the `res.send()` nested in the `findOne()` code will respond in the right order as you would expect.

At the end of the function, there's no need to return anything.

Comment: Chers Josh the information is great thank you for your time I really appreciate it. thanks!

Answer (score 1):

One problem with your code: on line 112, if an error has occurred, you just `console.log` and return. That's not right.

With Express, you always have to end the current request by sending back a response, even when an error happened. Otherwise, the request will never end and it will look like it is stalling. So one way to deal with errors in Express app is to return an HTTP 500 response:

```
if (err) {
  console.log("findOne -> Error!");
  return res.send(500, 'An error has occurred!');
}
```

Otherwise, as @JoshB pointed out, it should work.

Comment: Thanks for that any thing constructive is great while I am trying to understand the execution cycles of node, thanks again appreciated!